# C# WCF is behaving like a single user instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have developed a new WCF service which runs in IIS and a ASP.NET web application to consume this service. When running this on the server it works ok. However as soon as I accessed the service as multiple users (2 users) through an IE browser and Chrome Browser I noticed that when the second user signed in they were seeing data related to the 1st users session, making it impossible for more than 1 user to use the service at a time. I had assumed that the WCF service would automatically handle multiple sessions once the service was configured with: 
**[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]**

But this does not seem to be the case. Below is how I have defined my classes within the service and how MyGlob is initialized. I would realy appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong ?

> ```
> public UserMaster LoadUserDtls(string loggedInUserId, string userPassword)
>       {
>       try
>          {
>           // Create all objects required to bootstrap initial menu transaction
>                 MyGlob.CrtUserMaster();
>                 MyGlob.CrtEnterpriseMaster();
>                 MyGlob.CrtDataBaseIO();
>                 MyGlob.CrtExecuteTrans();
>                 MyGlob.CrtErrorMsgs();
>                 MyGlob.CrtPromptMsgs();
>                 MyGlob.CrtConnectionStrings();
>                 MyGlob.CrtLogMessages();
>                 MyGlob.CrtRuleTypeOpSeq();
>                 MyGlob.CrtErrMsgsList();
>                 MyGlob.CrtEnvironments();
>                 MyGlob.CrtPromptMsgsList();
>                 MyGlob.CrtConnStringList();
>                 MyGlob.CrtEnvironmentList();
>                 MyGlob.CrtLogMessagesDict();
>                 MyGlob.CrtRuleTypeOpSeqDict();
>                 MyGlob.CrtKeywordsDict();
>                 MyGlob.CrtCommands();
>                 MyGlob.CrtObjDict();
>                 MyGlob.CrtNextNumbers();
>                 MyGlob.CrtAppDistLstDict();
>                 MyGlob.CrtNextNumbersDict();
>                 g.MyDataBaseIO.ReceiveMyGlob(MyGlob);
>                 g.MyCommands.ReceiveMyGlob(MyGlob);
> ```

```
**Definition of Classes within the WCF Service**

namespace DCRules2
{
    public class globals
    {
        public static UserMaster MyUser;
        public static EnterpriseMaster MyEnterprise;
        public static TransactionHdr MyTransHdr;
        public static TransactionSeq MyTransSeq;
        public static TransactionsWaitingToLoad MyTransWaiting;
        public static ExecuteTrans MyExe;
        public static Commands MyCommands;
        public static ErrorMsgs MyErrMsgs;
        public static PromptMsgs MyPromptMsgs;
        public static ConnectionStrings MyConnString;
        public static Environments MyEnvironments;
        public static RuleTypeOpSeq MyRuleTypeOpSeq;
        public static LogMessages MyLogMessages;
        public static DataBaseIO MyDataBaseIO;
        public static ErrorsEncountered MyErrorsEncountered;
        public static DisplaySeq MyDisplaySeq;
        public static PassToServiceParms MyPassToServiceParms;
        public static RtnFromServiceParms MyRtnFromServiceParms;
        public static InputValues MyInpFldVal;
        public static Object MyVarObj;
        public static NextNumbers MyNextNumbers;
        public static TransOutput MyTransOutput;

        public static AppDistLst MyAppDistLst;

        public static List<TransactionHdr> MyTransHdrList;
        public static List<TransactionSeq> MyTransSeqList;
        public static List<Environments> MyEnvironmentList;
        public static List<ErrorMsgs> MyErrMsgsList;
        public static List<PromptMsgs> MyPromptMsgsList;
        public static List<ConnectionStrings> MyConnStringList;
        public static List<DisplaySeq> MyDisplaySeqList;
        public static List<TransactionsWaitingToLoad> MyTransWaitingList;
        public static List<ErrorsEncountered> MyErrorsEncounteredList ;
        public static List<InputValues> MyInpFldValList ;


        public static Dictionary<string, int> MyTagsDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyVarValuesDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyVarTypesDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyCondLvlsDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyRuleTypeOpSeqDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyLogMessagesDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyKeywordsDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, int[]> MyPrevSelDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, object> MyObjDict ;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyAppDistLstDict;
        public static Dictionary<string, string> MyNextNumbersDict;

        public static TransLvlValues MyTransLvlValues;
        public static SessionLvlValues MySessionLvlValues;
        public static AppLvlValues MyAppLvlValues;
        //*****************************
        // Create new Objects
        //*****************************
        public UserMaster CrtUserMaster()
        {
            MyUser = new UserMaster();
            return MyUser;
        }
        public EnterpriseMaster CrtEnterpriseMaster()
        {
            MyEnterprise = new EnterpriseMaster();
            return MyEnterprise;
        }
        public TransactionHdr CrtTransactionHdr()
        {
            MyTransHdr = new TransactionHdr();
            return MyTransHdr;
        }

        public TransactionSeq CrtTransactionSeq()
        {
            MyTransSeq = new TransactionSeq();
            return MyTransSeq;
        }

        public TransactionsWaitingToLoad CrtTransactionsWaitingToLoad()
        {
            MyTransWaiting = new TransactionsWaitingToLoad();
            return MyTransWaiting;
        }

        public ExecuteTrans CrtExecuteTrans()
        {
            MyExe = new ExecuteTrans();
            return MyExe;
        }

        public Commands CrtCommands()
        {
            MyCommands = new Commands();
            return MyCommands;
        }

        public ErrorMsgs CrtErrorMsgs()
        {
            MyErrMsgs = new ErrorMsgs();
            return MyErrMsgs;
        }

        public PromptMsgs CrtPromptMsgs()
        {
            MyPromptMsgs = new PromptMsgs();
            return MyPromptMsgs;
        }

        public ConnectionStrings CrtConnectionStrings()
        {
            MyConnString = new ConnectionStrings();
            return MyConnString;
        }

        public Environments CrtEnvironments()
        {
            MyEnvironments = new Environments();
            return MyEnvironments;
        }

        public RuleTypeOpSeq CrtRuleTypeOpSeq()
        {
            MyRuleTypeOpSeq = new RuleTypeOpSeq();
            return MyRuleTypeOpSeq;
        }

        public LogMessages CrtLogMessages()
        {
            MyLogMessages = new LogMessages();
            return MyLogMessages;
        }

        public DataBaseIO CrtDataBaseIO()
        {
            MyDataBaseIO = new DataBaseIO();
            return MyDataBaseIO;
        }

        public ErrorsEncountered CrtErrorsEncountered()
        {
            MyErrorsEncountered = new ErrorsEncountered();
            return MyErrorsEncountered;
        }

        public DisplaySeq CrtDisplaySeq()
        {
            MyDisplaySeq = new DisplaySeq();
            return MyDisplaySeq;
        }

        public PassToServiceParms CrtPassToServiceParms()
        {
            MyPassToServiceParms = new PassToServiceParms();
            return MyPassToServiceParms;
        }

        public RtnFromServiceParms CrtRtnFromServiceParms()
        {
            MyRtnFromServiceParms = new RtnFromServiceParms();
            return MyRtnFromServiceParms;
        }

        public InputValues CrtInputValues()
        {
            MyInpFldVal = new InputValues();
            return MyInpFldVal;
        }
        public Object CrtVarObj()
        {
            MyVarObj = new Object();
            return MyVarObj;
        }
        public NextNumbers CrtNextNumbers()
        {
            MyNextNumbers = new NextNumbers();
            return MyNextNumbers;
        }
        public AppDistLst CrtAppDistLst()
        {
            MyAppDistLst = new AppDistLst();
            return MyAppDistLst;
        }
        public TransLvlValues CrtTransLvlValues()
        {
            MyTransLvlValues = new TransLvlValues();
            return MyTransLvlValues;
        }
        public SessionLvlValues CrtSessionLvlValues()
        {
            MySessionLvlValues = new SessionLvlValues();
            return MySessionLvlValues;
        }
        public AppLvlValues CrtAppLvlValues()
        {
            MyAppLvlValues = new AppLvlValues();
            return MyAppLvlValues;
        }
        public TransOutput CrtTransOutput()
        {
            MyTransOutput = new TransOutput();
            return MyTransOutput;
        }
        //*****************************
        // Create new List Objects
        //*****************************


        public List<TransactionHdr> CrtTransHdrList()
        {
            MyTransHdrList = new List<TransactionHdr>();
            return MyTransHdrList;
        }

        public List<TransactionSeq> CrtTransSeqList()
        {
            MyTransSeqList = new List<TransactionSeq>();
            return MyTransSeqList;
        }

        public List<Environments> CrtEnvironmentList()
        {
            MyEnvironmentList = new List<Environments>();
            return MyEnvironmentList;
        }

        public List<ErrorMsgs> CrtErrMsgsList()
        {
            MyErrMsgsList = new List<ErrorMsgs>();
            return MyErrMsgsList;
        }

        public List<PromptMsgs> CrtPromptMsgsList()
        {
            MyPromptMsgsList = new List<PromptMsgs>();
            return MyPromptMsgsList;
        }

        public List<ConnectionStrings> CrtConnStringList()
        {
            MyConnStringList = new List<ConnectionStrings>();
            return MyConnStringList;
        }

        public List<DisplaySeq> CrtDisplaySeqList()
        {
            MyDisplaySeqList = new List<DisplaySeq>();
            return MyDisplaySeqList;
        }

        public List<TransactionsWaitingToLoad> CrtTransWaitingList()
        {
            MyTransWaitingList = new List<TransactionsWaitingToLoad>();
            return MyTransWaitingList;
        }
        public List<ErrorsEncountered> CrtErrorsEncounteredList()
        {
            MyErrorsEncounteredList = new List<ErrorsEncountered>();
            return MyErrorsEncounteredList;
        }

        public List<InputValues> CrtInpFldValList()         
        {
            MyInpFldValList = new List<InputValues>();
            return MyInpFldValList;
        }


        //*****************************
        // Create new Dictionary Objects
        //*****************************

        public Dictionary<string, int> CrtTagsDict()
        {
            MyTagsDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            return MyTagsDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtVarValuesDict()
        {
            MyVarValuesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyVarValuesDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtVarTypesDict()
        {
            MyVarTypesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyVarTypesDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtCondLvlsDict()
        {
            MyCondLvlsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyCondLvlsDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtRuleTypeOpSeqDict()
        {
            MyRuleTypeOpSeqDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyRuleTypeOpSeqDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtLogMessagesDict()
        {
            MyLogMessagesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyLogMessagesDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtKeywordsDict()
        {
            MyKeywordsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyKeywordsDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, int[]> CrtPrevSelDict()
        {
            MyPrevSelDict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
            return MyPrevSelDict;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> CrtObjDict()
        {
            MyObjDict = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            return MyObjDict;
        }
        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtAppDistLstDict()
        {
            MyAppDistLstDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyAppDistLstDict;
        }
        public Dictionary<string, string> CrtNextNumbersDict()
        {
            MyNextNumbersDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            return MyNextNumbersDict;
        }
```

> ```
> **Here is how I initialize MyGlob**
> namespace DCRules2
>  {
>      [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
>      class TransactionService : ITransaction
>      {
>          public static globals MyGlob = new globals();
>
>          //public static globals MyGlob = globals.CrtGlobals();
>          //globals MyGlob = g.MyGlob.CrtGlobals();
>          RegDetails MyRegDetails;
>          Object MyVarObj;
>          DataSet MyDs;
>          DataTable dt2;
>          DataRow dtRow;
> ```

Comment: This is really bad. Stateful WCF services have many problems. You need to research that issue and drop that approach. Seeing you store DataTables and such in WCF service instances is really bad. Also, why are you using DataTables at all? They are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the "static" keywords. Any "static" class will be created once when the application is loaded into memory. Therefore, a single instance will be shared amongst all requests.